# How can I get this regex column search to work in datatables?

Tags: regex, datatables

I am using the jquery plugin Datatables 1.10.5.  I get my data serverside. In column 11, there are several possibilities which include "new" and "pending".  I want to apply a filter on that column so that only the rows with "new" OR "pending" are rendered.  I believe the only way I can do this is by using a regular expression.  This is what I have, but it is not working, I get no results back even though there are several that meet the condition.

```
    table.columns(11).search( "(new|pending)", true, false).draw();
```

Where have I gone wrong, or is there a totally different way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: From [the reference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) : `Note that to perform a smart search, DataTables uses regular expressions, so if enable regular expressions using the second parameter to this method, you will likely want to disable smart searching as the two regular expressions might otherwise conflict and cause unexpected results.`

Comment: Are you sure it is column 11 (0 indexed..)? Because your code above works fine for me.

Comment: Enissay, I saw that, that is why the 3rd parameter is there, that should turn off the smart searching.
Shiffty, yes, I'm sure I have the right column because if I try just "new" with the regular search it works.  But if it worked for you, then perhaps it must be something else besides my code here.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Shiffty, did you try it with getting the data server side?  I'm wondering if that would make a difference.

Comment: @xena If you get your data server side you should consider filtering the data on the server side aswell and return the filtered data. If you call the search method above you should retrieve the search params with the request.

Comment: I have a select with the options "all" and "new and pending".  The code I posted I was in an onchange function for the select element.   What I ended up doing was reloading the page onchange and sending a parameter in my ajax request to filter server side.  So didn't really solve my original problem, but it works.